# Perl copy to clipboard not working with Clipboard module

Tags: perl, ubuntu, command, ubuntu-14.04, geany

I have Perl 5.18.2 version installed in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Now I have created a custom command in geany which I am firing as below:

```
perl /home/ubuntu/geany_custom_cmds/get_current_directory_path.pl %f %d %e
```

And below is the code of `get_current_directory_path.pl` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# print $ARGV[0];
use Clipboard;
foreach $argnum (0 .. $#ARGV) {
    print "$ARGV[$argnum]\n";
    Clipboard->copy($ARGV[$argnum]);
    print Clipboard->paste;
}
```

But I am not getting any argument's value in my Ubuntu clipboard which I can paste by Ctrl + V.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program that you write

Comment: I tried to install Win32::Clipboard in my Windows 7 system but that fails too and so I can't use Win32::Clipboard. I am getting some tests failed error

Answer (score 1):

The [`Clipboard`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Clipboard) module is written to perform equally well on Windows, Mac, and Linux systems. To achieve that it has three different driver modules which implement the functionality

The Linux driver uses the `xclip` command-line tool, which isn't installed by default on Ubuntu. You must install it with

```
sudo apt install xclip
```

before the module will work for you

There really should be a comment to this effect in the module's documentation, as it is far from obvious

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that X-windows has three different cut-and-paste concepts:

- the "primary selection" (can be pasted with middle-mouse)
- the "secondary selection" (not relevant here)
- the "clipboard" (can be pasted with ^V)

Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel

Evidently the perl Clipboard package only knows about the primary selection.
You probably want both "primary" and "clipboard", or at least "clipboard".

Working code to solve this problem under X-windows can be found at https://www.av8n.com/security/Xclip.pm

Invoke as:

```
use Xclip;
Xclip::copy2("some stuff");
```

Requires either `xsel` or `xclip` to be installed.